# Passing Variable via AJax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im on project to make an app with codeigniter but i got stuck, when i want to pass same variable outside field via ajax into controller i got error the variable is not defined.

this is a example.

```
  $("#form_status_update").submit(function() {
          var date = new Date().toString();`
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>socialcontroller/setdate",
                    data:date,
                    success: function(data) {
                       window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url()?>socialcontroller/ssetdate";

                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
                    }
                });
            });
```

after passing some var i want to insert into my database.
and my question is how to pass a variable not field into controller via ajax thanks, i already search on google but i didnt geting the right answer :)
`

Comment: Is the ` on the second line a copy/paste error? You probably shouldn't use 'date' as the name of the variable since it is a keyword.

Comment: @JayBlanchard how is `date` a key word?

Comment: thats just an example, i just want to pass a variable not field into controller via ajax

Comment: date is key word yup, but that is just an example i want to pass some var into controller via ajax, and that var is not a field, im stuck with this :(

Comment: Well, not a keyword @epascarello - but the name of a built-in method, which could be confusing down the line.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Date != date

Comment: I know! And *it doesn't matter*! It can be confusing to some, that's all I'm saying @epascarello :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that help you with your problem
You can just adapt it with your code and it should work !

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("button").click(function(){
           var myDate = new Date();
            $.ajax({
            // Send with POST mean you must retrieve it in server side with POST
            type: 'POST',
            // change this to the url of your controller
            url:"index.php",
            // Set the data that you are submitting
            data:({date:myDate}),

            success:function(result){
              // Change here with what you need to do with your data if you need of course
              $("#div1").html(result);

            }});
          });
        });         
</script>

<body>

<div id="div1">
   <p>Today date here</h2>
  </div>
<button> Get Date< /button>
</body>

</html>
```

and your PHP code can be something like this !

```
<?php

// This line of code should get your data that you are sending
$data = $_POST['date'];

/// This code was just for checking purpose that it is returning the same value through ajax
$arr = array(
'receive_date'=>$data, 
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I think this code can work with must of MVC framework if you are setting your controller URL as url parameter. Check also the Framework documentation about getting the data through POST !

Answer (score 2):

The line `data:date,` is wrong. You are passing up a number on the querystring and not a key/value pair.

It needs to be

```
data: {date : date},
```

or

```
data: "date=" + encodeURIComponent(date),
```

---

[From jQuery Docs:](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **data**
>
> *Type:* PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the
>   server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
>   It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Comment: how about the controller?

Comment: What about the controller? What does it expect?

Comment: im still confuse, how to get that var in controller codeigniter, i have to write like this $date = $_GET['date']; or what? im sory im still confuse

Comment: I do not code in "codeigniter" so that I can not help you with.

Comment: how about in php without codeigniter?i think its still same

Comment: since you have set your ajax type to 'POST' it'll be in `$_POST["date"]` in your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

your selector `$("form_status_update")` doesn't match a **class** or an **id** of the **DOM**.
and it doesn't match an html element either. 
so this for sure gives you some (extra) problems.

Comment: i still didnt get the var in my controller, i already change into $("#form_status_update")

Answer (score 0):

couldnt you have tried running the date function at the php controller youre calling from the ajax function.
i dont see any specific reason as to why you have to send in date as the input parameter from the javascript function.

remove the date var and data field.
and in your php controller.
when you get the controller called.
run a date function in the php code and use the date from there.